# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android

I'm getting the following error in a Galaxy J5 (Android 6.0) when trying to save an image:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/FA49-E5D3/DCIM/Camera/20170311_140435.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In Activity:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        System.out.println("checking permissions...");
        // -------------------------------------- PERMISOS CAMARA -------------------------------------------------
        if (checkSelfPermission("android.permission.CAMERA") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA"}, 137);
            return;
        }
        // ---------------------------------- PERMISOS READ EXTERNAL ---------------------------------------------
        if (checkSelfPermission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}, 139);
            return;
        }
        // ---------------------------------- PERMISOS WRITE EXTERNAL ---------------------------------------------
        if (checkSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"}, 138);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("API < 23... Skip permissions...");
    }
```

Note that this is working fine in a Motorola G3 (Android 6.0) saving the image in this path:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170311_115623958.jpg
```

Comment: Show are you gtetting that path?

Comment: public String getOriginalImagePath() {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToLast();

        return cursor.getString(column_index_data);
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to write a file on a micro SD card. But they are read only for apps nowadays. Only a system camera app could have permission to write in the DCIM folder on SD.

Have a look at the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs(). Your app can write in that app specific directory on SD card.